# Invalid Object Name Sys.objects

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am new to sql i am executing a query which return error `Invalid object name 'sys.objects'.
I have the basic knowledge that columns tables,e.t.c is stored in system schema, if true than why i get this error.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.objects
```

Comment: Perhaps you are using MySQL and trying to access a table in the SQL Server database.  MySQL doesn't have `sys.objects`; SQL Server does.

Comment: Did you restored your DB, or did it upgraded from a SQL Server 2000 database? Does the compatibility level higher than SQL Server 2000?

Comment: No, Can u tell me what is the difference between
select * from sys.objects

select * from sys.sysobjects

Comment: Are you on a case sensitive collation? The query you posted and the title of your thread have different casing on the sys schema. If you capitalize the first s in a case sensitive collation it will not find the view.

Answer (score 4):

The correct query is:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sysobjects
```

because the first `sys` is schema, but the name of table is `sysobjects` and no `objects`

You can also write

```
SELECT * FROM sysobjects
```

without explicit the schema.

In `sysobjects` table you can read all objects present in your DB (you can find tables, views, SP and so on)

Comment: i have created a table t is it not an object? why the upper query does not run?

Comment: Actually i was using this query i want to know the actual concept behind it table is treated like a object in the sql and the schema contains the information of the object than why sys.objects does not work? Is sys.objects is used for some other purpose??


IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sysobjects s WHERE s.name='Employee')
DROP TABLE Employee 
ELSE
 BEGIN 
  
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
 Employee_Id nvarchar(20),
 Employee_Name nvarchar(20),
 Employee_Age int 
)
  END

Comment: sys.sysobjects is a backwards compatibility view that is left around for sql 2000. The current view is sys.objects. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177596.aspx

Comment: @SeanLange: On Sql Server 2008 doesn't exist that view. So bilal_izloo can work on sys.sysobjects

Comment: @JoeTaras you are incorrect. sys.objects has been valid since 2005. Look again at the link I posted above, then switch to sql 2005. As it happens I just ran it on an old 2005 box and it still works. :)

Comment: @SeanLange: Ok, I'm wrong. So, it's very strange the case study posted by bilal_izloo!

Answer (score 3):

I have SQL Server 2000 and using SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects worked for me. (do instead of sys)

Comment: Starting with SQL Server 2005 there were MANY changes, including moving away from object owners to schemas and moving the catalog views to the `sys` schema. Your SELECT statement will still work in the newer versions due to backwards compatibility, but the OP is on SQL Server 2008 R2 and so should be using `sys.objects` instead, just like in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Like many other DBMS systems, SQL Server exposes meta data using catalog views and functions.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174365.aspx.  sysobjects (actually dbo.sysobjects) was replaced by sys.objects in SQL Server 2005, with sysobjects provided for backwards compatibility.

Catalog views like sys.objects are often used to assert the expected state of the database before running DDL scripts.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an issue of permissions. Starting in SQL Server 2005, all databases have a `sys.objects` system view so the query in the question is correct.

And this is not likely an issue of a case-sensitive database since the object names are in all lower case so even if case-sensitive, the query in the question is still correct. Of course, this assumes that the query in the question (all lower-case) and *not* the query in the title (mixed-case) is being used. As pointed out by @Sean in a comment on the question, a mixed-case system schema and/or object name will receive an "Invalid Object" error in a case-sensitive database.

I will try to find the exact permission(s), but either:

- some basic permission has not been granted (i.e. membership in the `public` built-in database role)

  or
- a DENY has been added somewhere in the permission chain

---

Well, interesting. So far all permissions attempts, including membership in the `db_denydatareader` built-in database role, result in the following (which at least acknowledges the existence of `sys.objects`):

> Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 2
> The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'objects', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.

Another option: what is the compatibility_level of the database set to? It is possible that it is set to `80` which corresponds to SQL Server 2000, which *should* have the effect of not knowing about `sys.objects`.